# How to create custom widget in XCP

Tags: widget, custom-controls, xcp2.x

I am using XCP. I want to create custom widget in it. So anybody knows how to create custom widget and how to debug that custom widget's code in design time.

Answer (score 0):

1. In the layout area of a page, perform Ctrl + Shift + Click. This opens the Firebug console.
2. In the Firebug console, type window.location.href and press Enter.
3. Select and copy the URL.
4. Open a Web browser, for example, Firefox or Chrome, and paste the URL.
5. Debug the script of your custom widget, as required.